# Add an onclick handler to the anchor tag

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

I dont know Add an onclick handler to the anchor tag.
I am learning with tutorial
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/account-geolocation-app/lc-app-08

where I should put the next line of code

```
<li><a onclick="{!c.accountSelected}">{!v.account.Name}</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
 <aura:component>
    <aura:registerEvent name="accountSelected" type="c:AccountSelected"/>
    <aura:attribute name="account" type="Account"/>
    <li><a onclick="{!c.accountSelected}">{!v.account.Name}</a></li>
</aura:component>
```